# Windows Mobile Emulator camera integration

Tags: windows-mobile, camera, emulation, video-camera

I'm using the [nyartoolkit](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wiki/index.php?NyARToolkitCS.en) to put together an augmented reality application but I am new to Windows Mobile emulation. Can anyone help me understand how I can get live video into the mobile emulator? Is there any way to bridge to my web cam for example?

Comment: I had the same problem with Symbol Barcode scanners.

Comment: I don't know why you want to use camera in emulator, not on real device. Emulator is usually slow. Furthermore, cameras support is (?was) very ugly in winMobile. It's standardized only in winMobile5 and only via DirectShow filters. And many vendors don't release good enough DShow filters to access all features/resolutions/FPS of their cameras. So what you'll receive emulated may very differ from what you will get on the device(s).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, there is no support in Device Emulator to input video for the camera. Where the emulator supports a camera at all, you'll just get some generated patterns. Sorry.

(Does NyAR have any way to accept video input from another source, such as a virtual serial port or the network? My Japanese is not up to the job of reading the doc...)

Comment: I expect it would be possible to mock it up as the feed is currently sourced through a utility project called NyWMCaptureCS. So much for simply 'knocking up a prototype' ;)